# How to restart your whole app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created this app where the app generates a list of random symbols but every 5th element has same symbol and that symbol is later printed in the end. Everything is working fine till I reach the last page and I want to create a button to refresh the whole app and the symbols become random again. I tried to use the button and linked it to go to first page again but the icons remained same.

This is my code, sorry if it's messy I am new:-
https://dartpad.dev/725f4a6f4bd97c5a4a9e43b2af9159d6

https://pastebin.com/k4ZTWiSE

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import "dart:math";

var list = ['❤', '✌', '', '', '', '', '❄', ''];
List<dynamic> notes = new List();

final _random2 = new Random();
var element2 = list[_random2.nextInt(list.length)];
var x = element2;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp()
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int index = 0;

  List<dynamic> myText = [
    'All symbols are random',
    'but all number divisible by 5 have same symbols',
    'last page will show you the common symbol',
  ];

  void changeText() {
    setState(() {
      index++;
      if (index == myText.length) {
        index = 0;

        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
        );
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0) {
          notes.add('${i + 1}.) $x');
        } else {
          final _random = new Random();
          var element = list[_random.nextInt(list.length)];

          notes.add('${i + 1}.) $element');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('random'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                child: Text(
                  myText[index],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
        onPressed: changeText,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondRouteState createState() => _SecondRouteState();
}

class _SecondRouteState extends State<SecondRoute> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("random"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.white10,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: HomePage(notes),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute2()),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<dynamic> notes;

  HomePage(this.notes);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.notes.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, pos) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0, horizontal: 16.0),
              child: Text(
                widget.notes[pos],
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  height: 1.6,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("List"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.white10,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Text('$x'),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: () => MyApp));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your repeated element is this, set at the file scope:

```
var element2 = list[_random2.nextInt(list.length)];
```

In your `changeText` function, simply reassign it like this:

```
  void changeText() {
    setState(() {
      // not needed after all! final _random = new Random(); // add this
      element2 = list[_random2.nextInt(list.length)]; // ... and this
      x = element2; // and this
      index++;
      if (index == myText.length) {
        index = 0;
        notes=[]; // update: add this
```

You don't have to restart the app -- just reassign.  Note: you have `element2` and `x` which appear to always have the same value.  You should probably just pick one variable and use it rather than having two with the same value.

Comment: Thanks that worked for the last screen but the list is still the same 
 .https://dartpad.dev/725f4a6f4bd97c5a4a9e43b2af9159d6

Comment: Oh I guess I misunderstood what you wanted.  I edited my answer to add the line `notes=[]`.  That works.  Previously it was just adding to the end of the `notes` list so the list got longer and longer (100, then 200, then 300...)

Comment: Also note that you don't need the line I'd added `final _random = new Random()`.  I'd misread your code.

Comment: @Cybercop if that answers your question, please accept the answer.